# Overriding specific css properties in vue-vuetify project

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify in my vuejs project and my scenario is this.

When I use v-card, then I want `box-shadow: 3px 3px 30px #95959522;` every time, for which I have overridden in my main css file as

```
.v-card {
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 30px #95959522 ;
}
```

But if I use the default properties such as `v-card flat` or `v-card raised`, then I definitely want the `box-shadow` which comes along with the specified properties, but currently all the v-card have the `box-shadow` as defined above, and the flat and raised prop are not available any longer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:not` keyword to exclude `flat`, `raised` or any other cases.

```
.v-sheet.v-card:not(.v-card--raised):not(.v-card--flat) {
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 30px #959595;
}
```